# New package submitted to CTAN, but cannot be found by tlmgr

Tags: packages, texlive, ctan

I submitted a new package to CTAN days ago. I can find this package on CTAN, but my texlive installation cannot find it via tlmgr.
How long does it take for CTAN new package to be installed in texlive?
Should I wait for texlive 2016?

Comment: If you are using TeXLive 2015 it should show up soon.  But some mirrors take longer to update than others.

Comment: Is the package 'license-free' (so it can be added to TeX LIve)?

Comment: From my own experience: Usually it takes two days until the package enters the TL distribution

Comment: I've just checked. If `seuthesix` is the package in question -- it's on TeXLive 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually there's a time lag between uploading on CTAN and transmitting it from CTAN to TeXLive (given the license is correct) -- it takes sometimes up to two days until packages are available for the distributions. (From clemens' comment: If TeXLive is frozen, it takes longer of course until the packages are taken from CTAN)

The relevant package (most likely `seuthesix`) entered CTAN some days ago and is available on TeXLive too, both by the command line version of `tlgmr` as well as the gui version:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it takes longer than two days (not speaking about the time when TL is frozen) but that is rather rare. I'm always amazed how fast TL is up to date.

Comment: @clemens: That's why I wrote `sometimes`. But the `freeze` is a good point. I'll add that.

Comment: What I really wanted to say: the CTAN team and the TL team are awesome :)